# Generate 256 numbers using /dev/urandom in Assembly;

Tags: assembly, x86, 32-bit

I would like to know how to use /dev/urandom to generate numbers in assembly 32 bits.
I know i should that i should have the name of the file "/dev/urandom" in memory :

```
segment.data :
file : db "/dev/random",10
len : equ $-file
index : db "1",10
lenindex : equ $-index
```

then I should read the file in my loop to generate a number and write 1 in the index of the generated number, here is my loop

```
loop1 : xor ecx,ecx
        cmp ecx,256
        je end_loop1
        mov EAX, 5
        mov ebx, file
       mov ecx, 0; o for octal // I guess this is how i generate a number (by reading it)
     mov edx, 0001o;o for octal // Permission on file.
       inc ecx
       int 0x80;
       mov ebx,eax
       mov eax,4
       mov ecx,index
       mov edx,lenindex
       int 0x80
       jmp loop1
```

as u may constat, I'm a beginner in assembly 32 bits I would love if someone explains how can I generate numbers using /dev/urandom and indicate 1 in the index of the generated number.

Comment: @IMSoP: `int 0x80` traps to the OS, it's the standard way to make Linux system calls in 32-bit x86 hand-written asm.  (For high performance, you'd `call` into the VDSO page which will use `sysenter`, but `int 0x80` is simpler.)  EAX=5 / int 0x80 is sys_open (which doesn't belong inside the loop).  EAX=4 / int 0x80 is sys_write, but there's no `sys_read` in the loop.

Comment: @N_Craft: this is an infinite loop.  Use a different register for your loop counter, ECX is needed for system-call inputs.  `xor ecx,ecx`  does ECX=0, so you're basically doing `while(0 != 256) { write( open("/dev/urandom", 0), index, lenindenx); }`.  i.e. trying to write to /dev/urandom after opening it read-only.  (if O_RDONLY=0, I forget.)  I'd suggest using C to start with and writing a sane loop, then implementing that in asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks for the help. however, i have a little knowledge in 32 assembly, and a lot of confusions. I don't know how to use a loop otherwise.. ; if i can't use ecx, which register can i use to increment and compare ?

Comment: ECX is not special unless you're using the `loop` instruction (which you shouldn't because it's slow).  `cmp` works with any register.  ESI or EDI would be good choices here because the int 0x80 ABI doesn't touch them.

Comment: I have never seen those registers but i will use them, thank you. Is my code indeed generating and writing "1" in the index ?

Comment: 32-bit x86 only has 8 general-purpose registers.  If you aren't aware of all of them, and super basics like how to loop with `dec reg` / `jnz .top_of_loop`, you need to go back to basics and read a tutorial / guide that introduces the basics of the architecture before you start trying to write programs that make system calls.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, beg everybody's pardon, I didn't see that. I should have left the question to the experts. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get 256 random bytes at once and print them (NASM assembler):

```
SECTION .data                   ; Section containing initialised data

    file db "/dev/urandom",0
    txt db " random bytes generated", 0x0A, 0x0A
    txt_len EQU $ - txt
    index dd 0

SECTION .bss                    ; Section containing uninitialised data
    decstr resb 40              ; 40 Bytes for an ASCII string
    decstr_len resd 1
    filedescriptor resd 1
    numbers resb 256

SECTION .text                   ; Section containing code
global  _start                  ; Linker needs this to find the entry point!
_start:

    ; http://www.lxhp.in-berlin.de/lhpsysc1.html#open
    mov eax, 5                  ; SYSCALL open
    mov ebx, file               ; File descriptor
    mov ecx, 0                  ; Access: read only
    mov edx, 0x00004            ; Mode: read by others
    int 0x80                    ; Call Linux kernel
    mov [filedescriptor], eax   ; Store the resulting fd

    ; http://www.lxhp.in-berlin.de/lhpsysc1.html#read
    mov eax, 3                  ; SYSCALL read
    mov ebx, [filedescriptor]   ; File descriptor
    mov ecx, numbers            ; Pointer to input buffer
    mov edx, 256                ; Max. count of bytes to read
    int 0x80                    ; Call Linux kernel
    mov [index], eax            ; Store the count of bytes received

    ; http://www.lxhp.in-berlin.de/lhpsysc1.html#close
    mov eax, 6                  ; SYSCALL close
    mov ebx, [filedescriptor]   ; File descriptor
    int 0x80                    ; Call Linux kernel

    ; Print index
    mov eax, [index]            ; Argument: Integer to convert
    mov edi, decstr             ; Argument: Address of the target string
    call int2str                ; Get the digits of EAX and store it as ASCII & LF & NUL
    sub edi, decstr             ; EDI (pointer to the terminating NULL) - pointer to decstr = length of the string
    dec edi                     ; Shorten the string by the LF
    mov [decstr_len], edi       ; Store the resulting length of the string

    ; http://www.lxhp.in-berlin.de/lhpsysc1.html#write
    mov eax, 4                  ; SYSCALL write
    mov ebx, 1                  ; File descriptor: STDOUT
    mov ecx, decstr             ; Pointer to output buffer
    mov edx, [decstr_len]       ; count of bytes to send
    int 0x80

    ; http://www.lxhp.in-berlin.de/lhpsysc1.html#write
    mov eax, 4                  ; SYSCALL write
    mov ebx, 1                  ; File descriptor: STDOUT
    mov ecx, txt                ; Pointer to output buffer
    mov edx, txt_len            ; count of bytes to send
    int 0x80

    ; Print the numbers
    mov esi, numbers            ; Start address for lodsb
L1:                             ; Loop to print <index> numbers
    xor eax, eax                ; Argument: Integer to convert
    lodsb
    mov edi, decstr             ; Argument: Address of the target string
    call int2str                ; Get the digits of EAX and store it as ASCII & LF & NUL
    sub edi, decstr             ; EDI (pointer to the terminating NULL) - pointer to decstr = length of the string
    mov [decstr_len], edi       ; Store the resulting length of the string

    ; http://www.lxhp.in-berlin.de/lhpsysc1.html#write
    mov eax, 4                  ; SYSCALL write
    mov ebx, 1                  ; File descriptor: STDOUT
    mov ecx, decstr             ; Pointer to output buffer
    mov edx, [decstr_len]       ; count of bytes to send
    int 0x80

    sub dword [index], 1
    jnz L1                      ; Do it again

    ; http://www.lxhp.in-berlin.de/lhpsysc1.html#exit
    mov eax, 1                  ; SYSCALL exit
    mov ebx, 0                  ; Exit Code
    int 80h                     ; Call Linux kernel

int2str:    ; Converts an positive integer in EAX to a string pointed to by EDI
    xor ecx, ecx
    mov ebx, 10
    .LL1:                       ; First loop: Collect the remainders
    xor edx, edx                ; Clear EDX for div
    div ebx                     ; EDX:EAX/EBX -> EAX Remainder EDX
    push dx                     ; Save remainder
    inc ecx                     ; Increment push counter
    test eax, eax               ; Anything left to divide?
    jnz .LL1                    ; Yes: loop once more

    .LL2:                       ; Second loop: Retrieve the remainders
    pop dx                      ; In DL is the value
    or dl, '0'                  ; To ASCII
    mov [edi], dl               ; Save it to the string
    inc edi                     ; Increment the pointer to the string
    loop .LL2                   ; Loop ECX times

    mov word [edi], 0x0A        ; Last characters: LF, NUL
    inc edi
    ret                         ; RET: EDI points to the terminating NULL
```

To get 256 random DWORDs one by one and print them one by one (NASM assembler):

```
SECTION .data                   ; Section containing initialised data

    file db "/dev/urandom",0    ; NUL terminated (ASCIZ)!
    loopcount dd 256

SECTION .bss                    ; Section containing uninitialised data

    decstr resb 40              ; 40 Bytes for an ASCII string
    decstr_len resd 1
    filedescriptor resd 1
    number resd 1

SECTION .text                   ; Section containing code
global  _start                  ; Linker needs this to find the entry point!
_start:

    ; http://www.lxhp.in-berlin.de/lhpsysc1.html#open
    mov eax, 5                  ; SYSCALL open
    mov ebx, file               ; File descriptor
    mov ecx, 0                  ; Access: read only
    mov edx, 0x00004            ; Mode: read by others
    int 0x80                    ; Call Linux kernel
    mov [filedescriptor], eax   ; Store the resulting fd

L1:                             ; Loop to print <loopcount> numbers

    ; http://www.lxhp.in-berlin.de/lhpsysc1.html#read
    mov eax, 3                  ; SYSCALL read
    mov ebx, [filedescriptor]   ; File descriptor
    mov ecx, number             ; Pointer to input buffer
    mov edx, 4                  ; Max. count of bytes to read
    int 0x80                    ; Call Linux kernel

    ; Print the number
    mov eax, [number]           ; Argument: Integer to convert
    mov edi, decstr             ; Argument: Address of the target string
    call int2str                ; Get the digits of EAX and store it as ASCII & LF & NUL
    sub edi, decstr             ; EDI (pointer to the terminating NULL) - pointer to decstr = length of the string
    mov [decstr_len], edi       ; Store the resulting length of the string

    ; http://www.lxhp.in-berlin.de/lhpsysc1.html#write
    mov eax, 4                  ; SYSCALL write
    mov ebx, 1                  ; File descriptor: STDOUT
    mov ecx, decstr             ; Pointer to output buffer
    mov edx, [decstr_len]       ; count of bytes to send
    int 0x80

    sub dword [loopcount], 1
    jnz L1                      ; Do it again

    ; http://www.lxhp.in-berlin.de/lhpsysc1.html#close
    mov eax, 6                  ; SYSCALL close
    mov ebx, [filedescriptor]   ; File descriptor
    int 0x80                    ; Call Linux kernel

    ; http://www.lxhp.in-berlin.de/lhpsysc1.html#exit
    mov eax, 1                  ; SYSCALL exit
    mov ebx, 0                  ; Exit Code
    int 80h                     ; Call Linux kernel

int2str:    ; Converts an positive integer in EAX to a string pointed to by EDI
    xor ecx, ecx
    mov ebx, 10
    .LL1:                       ; First loop: Collect the remainders
    xor edx, edx                ; Clear EDX for div
    div ebx                     ; EDX:EAX/EBX -> EAX Remainder EDX
    push dx                     ; Save remainder
    inc ecx                     ; Increment push counter
    test eax, eax               ; Anything left to divide?
    jnz .LL1                    ; Yes: loop once more

    .LL2:                       ; Second loop: Retrieve the remainders
    pop dx                      ; In DL is the value
    or dl, '0'                  ; To ASCII
    mov [edi], dl               ; Save it to the string
    inc edi                     ; Increment the pointer to the string
    loop .LL2                   ; Loop ECX times

    mov word [edi], 0x0A        ; Last characters: LF, NUL
    inc edi
    ret                         ; RET: EDI points to the terminating NULL
```

You can change the number in

```
mov edx, 4                  ; Max. count of bytes to read
```

to get another range, e.g.

```
mov edx, 2                  ; Max. count of bytes to read
```

for a WORD range (0..65535).

Comment: Thank you for these clarifications, i still don't understand why are u using a string ?

Comment: @N_Craft: The random numbers come as integers from `/dev/urandom`. There is no function in the Linux kernel to print them directly like in C: `printf ("%u\n",i);`. So, I have to convert them to strings and use the SYS_WRITE function.

Comment: I see ! Actually, i don't want to print them but make sure they are generated successfuly, but thanks for sharing this !